# How to Specify Role for SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

CDK will generate new role for each action in the pipline. I would like to use the pipeline role for all actions.

I can do it for `CodeCommitSourceAction` by specifying `role` property.

```js
    const sourceActionProps = {
      actionName: "CodeCommit",
      output: sourceArtifact,
      repository: repo,
      branch: code_repo_branch,
      role: role,
    };

    return new codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction(sourceActionProps);
```

But there is no similar property for `SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth`.

```js
pipelines.SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth({
      sourceArtifact,
      cloudAssemblyArtifact,
      installCommand: "npm install --include=dev",
      buildCommand: "npm run build",
      environment: {
        privileged: true,
      },
    });
```

Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the underlying project by saving it to a variable and updating the `project` property.

So

```
var synthAction = pipelines.SimpleSynthAction.standardNpmSynth(...)
synthAction.project.addToRolePolicy(<policyStatement>)
```

Or modify the `project.role` property to change the role entirely.